# drupal_get_form not working when called inside a block

Tags: forms, hooks

I have a custom module installed which displays a form at user/UID/apps/add. So, what this form does is lets user add node/nodes of "x" content type he/she wants in their app.
Form is created using this function-

*function devconnect_developer_apps_edit_form(array $form, array &$form_state, stdClass $account, $app_id = NULL)*

I'm trying to implement this form on every node so that the user can add that particular node to an existing or a new app on a button click.

Figured out I should be passing this nodeID as a default value to the form using drupal_get_form.
So created a block which renders the said form and to test if the form is being rendered I added it to a page to only see a 500 error.

Here is the block-

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Implements hook_block_info().
     */
    function sei_useapi_block_info() {
      $blocks = array();

      $blocks['MYBLOCK'] = array(
        'info' => t('My block'), 
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
      );
      return $blocks;
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_block_view().
     */
    function sei_useapi_block_view($delta = '') {
      $block = array();

      switch ($delta) {
        case 'MYBLOCK':
          $block['subject'] = t('My block title');
          $block['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('devconnect_developer_apps_edit_form'));
      }
      return $block;
    }
```

Don't have a clue what went wrong. Any ideas? Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to your form is $account, and it doesn't have a default argument. You aren't passing that block in your argument, which is why it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Rightly pointed, Thanks

For any other noobs like me out there-

```
'page arguments' => array('devconnect_developer_apps_edit_form', $user, NULL),
```